# Chromium os does't boot up

Tags: boot, chromium-os

I downloaded Chromium os from cloud ready 64bit as menotioned in this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2P0uRcdsTU)

After that i create recovery disk but it does't boot on startup not even flash drive meonotined in bios list